# Computational complexity of the 3-partition problem with distinct numbers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

This question is related to an [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/709/what-complexity-class-does-the-cutting-sticks-problem-belong-to/713#713) I posted in response to another question.

The 3-partition problem is the following problem:
*Instance*: Positive integers a<sub>1</sub>, …, a<sub>n</sub>, where n=3m and the sum of the n integers is equal to mB, such that each a<sub>i</sub> satisfies B/4 < a<sub>i</sub> < B/2.
*Question*: Can the integers a<sub>1</sub>, …, a<sub>n</sub> be partitioned into m multisets so that the sum of each multiset is equal to B?

It is well-known that the 3-partition problem is NP-complete in the strong sense that it remains NP-complete even if the numbers in the input are given in unary.  See [Garey and Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability:_A_Guide_to_the_Theory_of_NP-Completeness) for a proof.

**Questions**: Does the 3-partition problem remain NP-complete if the numbers a<sub>1</sub>, …, a<sub>n</sub> are all distinct?  Does it remain NP-complete in the strong sense?

(My feeling is that the answers to both questions are probably yes because I do not see any reason why the problem should become easier if all numbers are distinct.)

It does not seem that the proof in Garey and Johnson establishes the NP-completeness of this restricted version.

In the answer to the other question linked above, I gave a proof that the 6-partition problem (defined analogously) with distinct numbers is NP-complete in the strong sense.

Comment: I think this is an important problem; I found several papers in the literature that state or assume that the set version is hard, with no better justification than a citation to the multiset version in Garey and Johnson, and that use that assumption in a claim of NP-completeness for some other problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is proved in [1, Corollary 7], that 3-partition is strongly NP-hard when the integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are all distinct. The bounds $B/4 < a_i < B/2$ are not imposed in [1], but this should not make a difference.

[1]: Heather Hulett, Todd G. Will, Gerhard J. Woeginger: Multigraph realizations of degree sequences: Maximization is easy, minimization is hard. Oper. Res. Lett. 36(5): 594-596 (2008). [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.orl.2008.05.004)

Comment: Imposing the bounds $B/4 < a_i < B/2$ is easily done by adding the same large number to all of the $a_i$.

Comment: Indeed, it is straightforward to also impose these bounds.

Comment: Thanks, it answers my question completely.  Note that the partial Latin square completion problem can be easily formulated as a special case of the 3-dimensional matching.  It did not occur to me to replace 3DM by PLSC, but after seeing the proof, the approach seems quite natural.